# Different results using atoi

Tags: c++

Could someone explain why those calls are not returning the same expected result?

```
unsigned int GetDigit(const string& s, unsigned int pos)
{
      // Works as intended
      char c = s[pos];
      return atoi(&c);

      // doesn't give expected results
      return atoi(&s[pos]);
      return atoi(&static_cast<char>(s[pos]));
      return atoi(&char(s[pos]));
}
```

**Remark**: I'm not looking for the best way to convert a `char` to an `int`.

Comment: The "works as intended" one results in UB, since you are passing to `atoi` a single `char` instead of the null-terminated string it is expecting.

Comment: @littleadv: sure, I meant a *pointer* to a single `char`; and passing a pointer to a single char is surely UB, because you have no guarantees of what follows it on the stack (actually, it's UB without any doubt because you're making `atoi` access memory past the last element of the "array").

Comment: @Matteo: without any doubt, unless `s[pos]` happens to be a 0 byte, or otherwise a character that causes `atoi` to stop reading ;-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

None of your attempts are correct, including the "works as intended" one (it just happened to work by accident). For starters, `atoi()` requires a NUL-terminated string, which you are not providing.

How about the following:

```
unsigned int GetDigit(const string& s, unsigned int pos)
{
      return s[pos] - '0';
}
```

This assumes that you *know* that `s[pos]` is a valid decimal digit. If you don't, some error checking is in order.

Comment: `atoi` stops reading the input string at the first character that it cannot recognize as part of a number. This may be the null character. So it actually sounds like the null character is not definetly needed, isn't it? But nevertheless you are right, none of my solutions are correct.

Comment: @RonaldMcBean: The terminating character -- whatever it happens to be -- should be part of the string, since reading past the end of the string is undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 3):

What you are doing is use a `std::string`, get one character from its internal representation and feed a pointer to it into `atoi`, which expects a `const char*` that points to a NULL-terminated string. A `std::string` is not guaranteed to store characters so that there is a terminating zero, it's just luck that your C++ implementation seems to do this.

The correct way would be to ask `std::string` for a zero terminated version of it's contents using `s.c_str()`, then call `atoi` using a pointer to it.

Your code **contains another problem**, you are casting the result of `atoi` to an `unsigned int`, while `atoi` returns a signed `int`. **What if your string is "-123"**?

Comment: +1: for pointing out the other problem and a nice explanation

Answer (score 1):

Since `int atoi(const char* s)` accepts a pointer to a field of characters, your last three uses return a number corresponding to the consecutive digits beginning with &s[pos], e.g. it can give 123 for a string like `"123"`, starting at position 0. Since the data inside a `std::string` are not *required* to be null-terminated, the answer can be anything else on some implementation, i.e. undefined behaviour.

Your "working" approach also uses undefined behaviour. 
It's different from the other attempts since it *copies the value* of `s[pos]`to another location.
It seems to work only as long as the adjacent byte in memory next to character c accidentally happens to be a zero or a non-digit character, which is not guaranteed. So follow the advice given by @aix.

To make it work really you could do the following:

```
char c[2] = { s[pos], '\0' };
return atoi(c);
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to access the data as a C string - use `s.c_str()`, and then pass it to `atoi`.

`atoi` expects a C-style string, `std::string` is a C++ class with different behavior and characteristics. For starters - it doesn't have to be NULL terminated.

Answer (score 0):

`atoi` takes pointer to `char` for it's argument.  In the first try when you are using the `char c` it takes pointer to only one character hence you get the answer you want.  However in the other attempts what you get is pointer to a `char` which has happened to be beginning of a string of `char`s, therefore I assume what you are getting after `atoi` in the later attempts is a number converted from the chars in positions `pos`, `pos+1`, `pos+2` and up to the end of the `s` string.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to convert just a single char in the string at the position (as opposed to a substring starting at that position and ending at the end of the string), you can do it these ways:

```
int GetDigit(const string& s, const size_t& pos) {
    return atoi(string(1, s[pos]).c_str());
}

int GetDigit2(const string& s, const size_t& pos) {
    const char n[2] = {s[pos], '\0'};
    return atoi(n);
}
```

for example.